# Algorithm for Combinations of given numbers with repetition? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations, repeat

So I N - numbers I have to input, and I got M - numbers of places for those numbers and I need to find all combinations with repetition of given numbers.

Here is example:

Let's say that N is 3(I Have to input 3 numbers), and M is 4.
For example let's input numbers: 6 11 and 533.
This should be result

6,6,6,6

6,6,6,11

6,6,6,533

6,6,11,6

...

533,533,533,533

I know how to do that manualy when I know how much is N and M:

In example where N is 3 and M is 4:

int main()
{

```
int N = 3;
int M = 4;

int *numbers = new int[N + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    cin >> numbers[i];

for (int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b < N; b++)
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
            for (int d = 0; d < N; d++)
            {
                cout << numbers[a] << " " << numbers[b] << " " << numbers[c] << " " << numbers[d] << endl;
            }
return 0;
```

}

But how can I make algorithm so I can enter N and M via std::cin and I get correct resut?

Thanks.

Comment: Use recursion on the position you are filling in the output array.

Comment: Keep incrementing the last place until you reach 533. Then reset it to 6, and move left, turning all the 533's to 6's until you reach a number that isn't 533; increment that, and if it's now a 533 in the first place then you're done, otherwise go back to the last place and start over.

Comment: This job is typical for a dynamical programming approach.

Comment: Thanks for answers :) But can you write me a code if you got spare time? I never really used recursion too much in past so I don't really have an idea how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one short tip: don't use "new" or C-style arrays in C++ when we have RAII and much faster data structures.

For the solution to your problem I would suggest making separate function with recursion. You said you know how to do it manually so the first step in making it into algorithm is to tear down you manual solution step by step. For this problem when you solve it by hand you basically start with array of all first numbers and then for last position you just loop through available numbers. Then you go to the second last position and again loop through available numbers just now with the difference that for every number there you must also repeat the last spot number loop. Here is the recursion. For every "n"th position you must loop through available numbers and for every call the same function for "n+1"th number.

Here is a simplified solution, leaving out the input handling and exact print to keep code shorter and more focused on the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void printCombinations(const std::vector<int>& numbers, unsigned size, std::vector<int>& line) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        line.push_back(numbers[i]);
        if (size <= 1) { // Condition that prevents infinite loop in recursion
            for (const auto& j : line)
                std::cout << j << ","; // Simplified print to keep code shorter
            std::cout << std::endl;
            line.erase(line.end() - 1);
        } else {
            printCombinations(numbers, size - 1, line); // Recursion happens here
            line.erase(line.end() - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers = {6, 11, 533};
    unsigned size = 4;
    std::vector<int> line;
    printCombinations(numbers, size, line);
    return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks :)
So I should use std::vector instead of arrays[]?

Comment: Vectors are much more versatile and safe than classic C arrays. In your code when you are creating *numbers you are creating a possible memory leak with new if you move *numbers to another data and don't delete the original array (see dynamically allocated memory). For the numbers vector you could also use std::array but that would be little to no benefit from using vector.

Comment: If you want to use new to dynamically allocate memory, for every new you use there should be a delete somewhere.

Comment: I see that Game development is your hobby. I learned most of my C++ on Learncpp.com, I made a couple of games in Unity3D and 5-6 on SFML and I also worked a little bit in UnrealEngine4. Can you recommend me on what should I focus next? I'm in High School currently(Third year out of 4)

Comment: I'm currently studying as well and the game development is my hobby since last year. So far I've done some games in game maker studios, which I would totally recommend if you are just starting out. But as you said, you have some experience with unity and unreal engine, and both of them provide solid base. Just focus on creating games on whatever engine or platform you want, realese (or sell if you are confident enough), take feedback, improve and repeat. Recently I've started to experiment with OpenFrameworks and so far so good. Although not focused on games it's in C++ what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Totally there is no need for recursion here. This is a typical job for dynamic programming. Just get the first solution right for n = 1 (1 slot is available) which means the answer is `[[6],[11],[533]]` and then move on one by one by relying on the one previously memoized solution.

Sorry that i am not fluent in C, yet in JS this is the solution. I hope it helps.

```js
function combosOfN(a,n){
  var res = {};
  for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) res[i] = res[i-1] ? res[i-1].reduce((r,e) => r.concat(a.map(n => e.concat(n))),[])
                                                : a.map(e => [e]);
  return res[n];
}

var arr = [6,11,533],
      n = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(combosOfN(arr,n)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the easiest way to do dynamic nested for loops is to create your own stack and use recursion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void printCombinations(int sampleCount, const std::vector<int>& options, std::vector<int>& numbersToPrint) {
    if (numbersToPrint.size() == sampleCount) {
       // got all the numbers we need, print them.
       for (int number : numbersToPrint) {
           std::cout << number << " ";
       }
       std::cout << "\n";
    }
    else {
        // Add a new number, iterate over all possibilities
        numbersToPrint.push_back(0);
        for (int number : options) {
            numbersToPrint.back() = number;
            printCombinations(sampleCount, options, numbersToPrint);
        } 
        numbersToPrint.pop_back();
    }
}


void printCombinations(int sampleCount, const std::vector<int>& options)     {
    std::vector<int> stack;
    printCombinations(sampleCount, options, stack);
}


int main()
{
  printCombinations(3, {1,2,3});
}
```

output

```
1 1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 3 
1 2 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 3 
1 3 1 
1 3 2 
1 3 3 
2 1 1 
2 1 2 
2 1 3 
2 2 1 
2 2 2 
2 2 3 
2 3 1 
2 3 2 
2 3 3 
3 1 1 
3 1 2 
3 1 3 
3 2 1 
3 2 2 
3 2 3 
3 3 1 
3 3 2 
3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to solve this, that does't use recursion.

Let's say n=2 and m=3. Consider the following sequence that corresponds to these values:

000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

The meaning of this is that when you see a 0 you take the first number, and when you see a 1 you take the second number. So given the input numbers [5, 7], then 000 = 555, 001=557, 010=575 etc.

The sequence above looks identical to representing numbers from 0 to 7 in base 2. Basically, if you go from 0 to 7 and represent the numbers in base 2, you have the sequence above.

If you take n=3, m=4 then you need to work in base 3:
0000
0001
0002
0010
0011
0012
....

So you go over all the numbers from 0 to 63 (4^3-1), represent them in base 3 and follow the coding: 0 = first number, 1 = second number, 2 = third number and 3 = fourth number.

For the general case, you go from 0 to M^N-1, represent each number in base N, and apply the coding 0 = first number, etc.

Here is some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void convert_to_base(int number, char result[], int base, int number_of_digits) {
    for (int i = number_of_digits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int remainder = number % base;
        number = number / base;
        result[i] = '0' + remainder;
    }
}


int main() {
    int n = 2, m = 3;

    int num = pow(n, m) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        char str[33];

        convert_to_base(i, str, n, m);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```