# Sequentially generate strings based on predefined pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, recursion

I am working on a javascript project that requires the ability to cycle through all the possible outcomes of a pattern.

For example's sake I'll say a number and then 7 characters independently picked from string "qwertyuiop". I'd want it to start with `0qqqqqq` and then advance to `0qqqqqqw` then `0qqqqqqe` and so on.

Comment: (36 smallletters+10 numbers)^7 times, how should that much data be returned??

Comment: OK. So what is the question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I had done a previous work for [Algorithm for Combinations of given numbers with repetition? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40961020/4543207) in JS. Although the original algorithm is for an array of integers we can implement the same algorithm for strings as well. It uses a dynamical programming approach. Even if there will be a huge result depending on the number of characters you want, this one should do the job the fastest way possible. Here is the code for `n = 3` and input string `"qwerty"`; while for `n = 7` we should expect to get a results array of 279936 combinations. My humble AMD CPU junk completed this job in 86921ms.

```js
function combosOfN(a,n){
  var res = {};
  a = a.split("");
  for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) res[i] = res[i-1] ? res[i-1].reduce((r,e) => r.concat(a.map(n => { var t = e.slice(0);
                                                                                                 t.push(n);
                                                                                                 return t;
                                                                                               })),[])
                                                : a.map(e => [e]);
  return res[n].map(e => "0"+e.join(""));
}

var str = "qwerty",
      n = 3,
    res = [];

console.time("test");
res = combosOfN(str,n);
console.timeEnd("test");
console.log(res);
```

As for in all dynamic programming approaches we are starting from the minimal solution and progressing towards the final result. We start with an empty hash. The hash we keep looks like below and at the end the result is the nth item (It should explain the logic of the algorithm clearly)

```
{ '1': [ [ 'q' ], [ 'w' ], [ 'e' ], [ 'r' ], [ 't' ], [ 'y' ] ],
  '2': 
   [ [ 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 't' ],
     [ 't', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 'y' ] ],
  '3': 
   [ [ 'q', 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 'q', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 'q', 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 'w', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 'q', 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 'e', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 'q', 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 'r', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 'q', 't', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 't', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 't', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 't', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 't', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 't', 'y' ],
     [ 'q', 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 'q', 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 'q', 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 'q', 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 'q', 'y', 't' ],
     [ 'q', 'y', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 'q', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 'w', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 'e', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 'r', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 't', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 't', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 't', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 't', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 't', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 't', 'y' ],
     [ 'w', 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 'w', 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 'w', 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 'w', 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 'w', 'y', 't' ],
     [ 'w', 'y', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 'q', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 'w', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 'e', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 'r', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 't', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 't', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 't', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 't', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 't', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 't', 'y' ],
     [ 'e', 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 'e', 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 'e', 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 'e', 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 'e', 'y', 't' ],
     [ 'e', 'y', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 'q', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 'w', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 'e', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 'r', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 't', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 't', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 't', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 't', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 't', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 't', 'y' ],
     [ 'r', 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 'r', 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 'r', 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 'r', 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 'r', 'y', 't' ],
     [ 'r', 'y', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 'q', 't' ],
     [ 't', 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 'w', 't' ],
     [ 't', 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 'e', 't' ],
     [ 't', 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 'r', 't' ],
     [ 't', 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 't', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 't', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 't', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 't', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 't', 't' ],
     [ 't', 't', 'y' ],
     [ 't', 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 't', 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 't', 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 't', 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 't', 'y', 't' ],
     [ 't', 'y', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 'q', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 'q', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 'q', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 'q', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 'q', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 'q', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 'w', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 'w', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 'w', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 'w', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 'w', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 'w', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 'e', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 'e', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 'e', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 'e', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 'e', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 'e', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 'r', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 'r', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 'r', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 'r', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 'r', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 'r', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 't', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 't', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 't', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 't', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 't', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 't', 'y' ],
     [ 'y', 'y', 'q' ],
     [ 'y', 'y', 'w' ],
     [ 'y', 'y', 'e' ],
     [ 'y', 'y', 'r' ],
     [ 'y', 'y', 't' ],
     [ 'y', 'y', 'y' ] ] }
```